# Web Api 2 Decimal delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How to create a model binder for decimal numbers which will throw exception if users are sending it in a wrong format?

I need something like this:

```
2 = OK
2.123 = OK
2,123 = throw invalid format exception
```

Comment: Exception will be thrown any way if binding to `decimal` type will not succeed.

Comment: yeah, this would make sense the other way around but you want the default. Which it should just do. Have you tested this?

Comment: @fabio this is not true. I just tested it. It is culture dependent. I have sent 10.5 to my api, and it binded well, but when i sent 10,5, it did not threw any exception. It just set my decimal value in my model as 0, which is default decimal value.

Comment: I think will be better if you show a request data you send and model you bounded to

Comment: If binding fail your model will be passed to controller's method as `null`

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article http://haacked.com/archive/2011/03/19/fixing-binding-to-decimals.aspx/

You can just use standard binder with simple check like this

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;

        if (valueResult.AttemptedValue.Contains(","))
        {
            throw new Exception("Some exception");
        }
        actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);


        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        bindingContext.Model = actualValue;
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT: According to @Liam suggestion you have to add this binder to your configuration first

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Above code throws exception in the case of bad decimal separater, but you should use model validation to detect that kind of errors. It is more flexible way.

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        ModelState modelState = new ModelState { Value = valueResult };
        object actualValue = null;
        try
        {
            if (valueResult.AttemptedValue.Contains(","))
            {
                throw new Exception("Some exception");
            }
            actualValue = Convert.ToDecimal(valueResult.AttemptedValue,
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            modelState.Errors.Add(e);
            return false;
        }

        bindingContext.ModelState.Add(bindingContext.ModelName, modelState);
        bindingContext.Model = actualValue;
        return true;
    }
}
```

you don't throw exception but just add validation error. You can check it in your controller later

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
}
```

Comment: You need to add about how to actually bind this too, i.e. `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());`

Comment: For WebAPI2 the `BindModel` method returns `bool`. We don't use MVC here

Comment: yes, sorry, I did notice this. Hence my deleted comment. I didn't realise microsoft had two interfaces with the same name but different signatures.....Seems like a bad idea to me. Interestingly that Phill Haacked article also seems to use the wrong one...

Comment: It was probably changed between some older versions of WebAPI. Current version have many differences from MVC

Comment: `ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());` requires IModelBinder Interface from `System.Web.Mvc`, but one used here is from `System.Web.Http.ModelBinding`